# Как разбить файл на строки пробелами с помощью библиотеки Tkinter в Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно разбить файл на строки по пробелам, используя виджет из Tkinter'а Text, и я попробовал это: `Text = Text.split(sep='\n')`, но я получаю ошибку "type object 'Text' has no attribute 'split'", подскажите, пожалуйста, как это решить.

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: хорошо, я перевёл

Answer (score 0):

```
t = Tk()
text = Text(master=t, height=20, width=20)
text.pack()
text.get("1.0",END).split(sep='\n')
```